# sampling .net 4/64 bit

Tags: .net, stack

so i tried below with rtllookupfunctionentry and unwind. this causes stack corruption. so anyone has this working

```
    GetThreadContext(hThread, &context))
    FunctionID Id = 0;
            ip=(LPCBYTE)context.Rip;
            HRESULT funcResult = info2->GetFunctionFromIP(iPointer, &id);

                ULONG64                       base = NULL;
                PRUNTIME_FUNCTION             func;
                func= RtlLookupFunctionEntry(context.Rip,               
                      &base, &unwindtbl);

                if (!func)
                {
                    // leaf
                    context.Rip  = (ULONG64)(*(PULONG64)context.Rsp);
                    context.Rsp += 8;
                }
                else
                {
                    ef = 0;
                    hd = NULL;

                    RtlVirtualUnwind(0, base, context.Rip, func,                    
                        &context, &hd,&ef,NULL);
```

Comment: There's no evidence of this code suspending the thread first.  Required.

Comment: sorry yes. I have suspended the thread before getting the context. it is not shown

Comment: You will probably find the fix will never be backported to .NET 4.0. You could contact MS for a QFE possibly.

Comment: It is a known bug for 4.0, specific to 64-bit processes.  Fixed in 4.5.  The use of "func" in the code snippet looks quite wrong.

Comment: what do you mean. func is the return from lookup

Comment: also if this is bug in 4.5 how is others doing it. the products which i download.

Comment: @user1705409 - It is not contained in 4.5, it likely will NOT be fixed in 4.0 because work aroudns exist.

Comment: @HansPassant: Can you please provide a connect link for this issue? It would be helpful :)

Comment: I just ran across a blog post from one of the team members.  No, don't have it anymore.